# Proper General Exception Handling after User-Defined Exception Handling

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, logic

I logically want to connect a user defined exception with general exception handling. Firstly, it should be checked whether the user defined exception is triggered. If it is not triggered, but another exception occurs, I want to print the exception information by `get_exception_info()`.

I have the following code:

```
class TestException(Exception):
    pass

def get_exception_info():
    try:
        exception_type, exception_value, exception_traceback = sys.exc_info()
        file_name, line_number, procedure_name, line_code = traceback.extract_tb(exception_traceback)[-1] #this line is properly indented in my file
        exception_info = ''.join('[Time Stamp]: '
            + str(time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S %p'))
            + '' + '[File Name]: ' + str(file_name) + ' '
            + '[Procedure Name]: ' + str(procedure_name) + ' '
            + '[Error Message]: ' + str(exception_value) + ' '
            + '[Error Type]: ' + str(exception_type) + ' '
            + '[Line Number]: ' + str(line_number) + ' '
            + '[Line Code]: ' + str(line_code))
        return exception_info
    except:
        pass

def test_func(x):

    try:
        if x > 0:
            raise TestException('wrong')
        elif x < 0:
            raise TestException('right')
        else:
            pass
    except TestException as e:
        print(e)
    except Exception:
        exception_info = get_exception_info()
        print(exception_info)
    finally:
        pass

test_func(a)
```

Theoretically, this would cause an Exception and it should print out the result of `get_exception_info()`. However I just get "NameError: name 'a' is not defined.

What am I doing wrong? And, more importantly probably, is this the right way to archieve my goal?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that the value `a` which you are passing into `test_func()` is not defined.

Add a line defining `a`, e.g.:

```py
# ...
a = "hello"
test_func(a)
```

#### EDIT:

For your code to work, you also need to import `time`, `traceback`, and `sys`. I would also suggest not catching exceptions inside `get_exception_info()`, as this may hide exceptions that you actually want to see, i.e.:

```py
import time
import traceback
import sys

class TestException(Exception):
    pass

def get_exception_info():
    exception_type, exception_value, exception_traceback = sys.exc_info()
    file_name, line_number, procedure_name, line_code = traceback.extract_tb(exception_traceback)[-1]
    exception_info = ' '.join([
        '[Time Stamp]:',
        time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S %p'),
        '[File Name]:',
        file_name,
        '[Procedure Name]:',
        procedure_name,
        '[Error Message]:',
        str(exception_value),
        '[Error Type]:',
        str(exception_type),
        '[Line Number]:',
        str(line_number),
        '[Line Code]:',
        line_code,
    ])

    return exception_info
# ...
```

#### EDIT II:

It sounds like the question revolves around how to catch an undefined variable (`a` in this case).

In that case, I would suggest adding a `try`-`except` block around the function call, e.g.:

```py
try:
    test_func(a)
except Exception:
    exception_info = get_exception_info()
    print(exception_info)
```

When `a` is undefined, this will generate something along the lines of:

```
[Time Stamp]: 13-06-2021 10:44:31 AM [File Name]: /path/to/sf_exc.py [Procedure Name]: <module> [Error Message]: name 'a' is not defined [Error Type]: <class 'NameError'> [Line Number]: 76 [Line Code]: test_func(a)
```

#### Comment

As a general remark, instead of manually formatting the error message, I would use Python's `logging` module which is powerful and gives a lot of flexibility when it comes to formatting different types of messages, using a custom [`Formatter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#formatter-objects). In particular, `Formatter` comes with methods that can be customised to treat [exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter.formatException) and [stack information](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter.formatStack).

Comment: I know, this is intentional. I want to trigger an exception, but I want that ```get_exception_info()``` is executed within that exception..

Comment: Yes, I thought so. If you pass in a string, the comparison attempt (`x >0`) will raise a `TypeError` with `'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`.

Comment: Hey @p3j4p5, I forgot to list my imports, I did them of course. 


But what I don't understand is what does ```(x>0)``` raise a ```TypeError```? How I understood Exceptions up to now is that if an exception occurs, the function looks whether there is a specificly defined procedure for the current exception, and, if not, would just trigger the usual Exception output. However, except Exception should catch the `TypeError`, as `TypeError` is a subclass of `Exception`, isn't it?

Comment: @Paul1911 - Yes, that's correct. When you pass in `a = "hello"` (i.e. `a` is a string), the comparison `x > 0` will raise a `TypeError` exception because you are trying to compare a string to an integer, which is not defined. Since this comparison is inside the `try`-`except` block it will be caught by `except Exception` and should print the `exception_info` message as you've defined it. In other words, passing in a string into `test_func()` is just a way to trigger and test the logic you've defined.

Comment: you're right, if I execute `test_func("hello")`, `exception_info` is returned - as expected. However if I stay with my undefined `a` as input, it still returns `TypeError` and not `exception_info`. I would want to get ´exception_info` here as well. This means that the exception for case `a` arises before the ´try´-´except´-block, right? do you know at which point exactly this is checked? Thanks so much already!

Comment: I'm starting to understand where you're coming from. I'm not an expert on this but I would guess, the evaluation of the variable `a` happens around the time a new stack frame is created for the call to `test_func()`. In other words, if you wanted to catch an exception raised in this case, you'd have to put the function call into a `try`-`except` block. I've updated the answer accordingly.